# Question about access token and refresh token in google API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, access-token, refresh-token

Currently, I am using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs. I got access token and refresh token, used the access token to connect to Google. Because the access token only lasts for 1 hour, I have to use refresh token to get new access token. However, reading the document:

```
There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user account per client.
```

does this mean that my refresh token can be used only 50 times or I can have 50 different refresh tokens (I would think by requesting new authorization). My English is not that good so sorry for asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user authenticates your application you are given an access token and a refresh token.  If the user then authenticates your application again you are given a new access token and refresh token.  Both will work.  This will continue up to 50 times where by the first one will then expire.

so

> There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user account per client.

Actually means that your application (client) can have 50 working refresh tokens per user account.

This is why if you are storing the refresh token you should update it every time the user authenticates your application to ensure that you have the most current one. Or even better would be to stop asking the user to authenticate the application if you already have a refresh token for them but this is not always possible.

Refresh tokens can be used as often as you want they do not expire unless they have not been used for a period of time (six months i think) or the user removes your access though there google account.